# Why cannot visual studio open my file for writing when building?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I was building a c++ project when Visual Studio gave me an error saying the main file cannot be opened for writing, even though my program does not write to any files.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   LNK1168 cannot open C:\Users\Nathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\c++thing\Debug\c++thing.exe for writing   c++thing    C:\Users\Nathan\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\c++thing\c++thing\LINK    1
```

Comment: It has to save the executable, right? :D Check if you're not running an instance of it. That would be blocking it. Only if you read the filename: `c++thing.exe`.

Comment: i cant close the process though

Comment: Sound likes you have Avast in your computer?

Comment: I do not but my Windows 10 computer is slow at times

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio (VS) 2015 is not managing to overwrite your application named "c++thing.exe".

It must got hanged while running by VS debugger (possibly on a windows 10 PC), and this debugger lose itself from main VS.

If SHIFT+F5 doesn't unlock the file (and terminate the process):

- try restarting VS
- [OR] terminate VS and then check the running processes list for "c++thing.exe" and kill it if still existing.